# Is it safe to disable Klarna magento 2,3 module?

Tags: magento2.3, klarnacheckout

We want to disable Klarna from our Magento installation, and will this be safe?

I can see the module is under vendor and not app/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we also had a 2.3 running, you can disable the modules. We nie upated to 2.4 and its disabled. Working well on both